# Sorting getting reset after model refresh in spiltapp

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, sapui5

We have a split app with sorting feature for the list in masterview. The sort happens properly. But when any submit action is triggered in detailview, the masterview is refreshed to remove the submitted listitem and the sorting is lost.

How do I retain the sorting? Is there a property I could refer to retain the sorting? I tried to store the sort key and sort order in sessionStorage and read it before refreshing the model and re-sort the returned data in array before assigning it to model.

I am pretty new to UI5, any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would be case if you are sorting via controller once the data is loaded.

You can either:

1. Add the [sorter to the list in the view](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/ec79a5d5918f4f7f9cbc2150e66778cc.html)  **OR**
2. Add [sorter at model level](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d2ce3f51e5e34198b0c1a7f6ddd98def.html)
   **OR**
3. After refresh apply the same sorting which you used to before.

*PS:I can add coding context if you can add your code in the question*